# Fetching configuration based on the user properties using Firebase Remote Config

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am using Firebase Remote Config feature to fetch some parameters required by the application. The parameter values depends on the `userProperty` which I have defined in the user properties tab in the Analytics section in Firebase.

Now, I want to get the parameter value for which the particular user property is true. I have defined condition using that user property. For example, lets say that the user property `screen_size` is what I have a defined condition for, such as if `screen_size` matches `AxB` then set a parameter named `mqtt_chat_enabled` to `true` and the default value is `false`.

When I fetch the remote config, I am getting the default value of `mqtt_chat_enabled` even if the `screen_size` is `AxB`.

The question is, how do we send the condition parameters when fetching the remoteConfig?

I tried using `setUserProperties` method before fetching remoteConfig, but it's not working.

I am not getting anything for this on the web. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. It turns out be issue with the firebase version. Upgrade your google play services and latest version of firebase, it should work then.

I am using firebase version 10.2.0